# What is the name of this operator property, when the result of operation is one of the operands?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the name of this property when

$ (\bigotimes_{a \in A} a ) \in A  $

that is the operator selects a member of A. Examples are min, max and median operators on ordered sets.
It seems to be similar to idempotency but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that the operator is a [choice function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function) from a subset of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ into $A$.

In fact, this is pretty much *exactly* what you're describing ("having sets as inputs and the output for each set is a member of that set").

The only details to consider are that the function might not be defined on the empty set, or might not be defined on infinitely many inputs. Considering that, the domain of your function might only be from $\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ (the nonempty subsets of $A$) or else the set $\mathcal{P}_{fin}(A)\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ ( nonempty finite subsets of $A$).

Each "rule" like min/max/median gives you the method of choosing an element out of the set.

Comment: I think closure more sounds like a "property".

Comment: @Siamak What "closure" do you mean?

Comment: the one in the first answer. The domain is closed wrt the operator.

Comment: Dear @Siamak : I just discovered that Scott removed the link I'm talking about. The solution is not bad, but I don't think it is very accurate. What you're describing is an operation that's closed on *every* nonempty subset (maybe only finite subsets) and that's a lot stronger than just plain old closure. And closure isn't really even a property of the operation, it's a property of the operation *and a set* upon which the operation is closed. The fact the operation is a choice function really seems to be a lot closer to what you're describing. Regards

Comment: I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it [closure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetClosure.html), or an operation closed on a particular set.

Comment: Hrm, I guess in a sense it is, but it's really much stronger than that, right? It's closed on *every* nonempty (finite maybe) subset.